# Selecting all rows where a set of column values is not null

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a complex table in Oracle which is intentionally not normalized.  It has a huge number of columns with observations in each col

something like

Table1
ID,obs1,obs2,obs2,obs3... obs100

Is there a way to select ALL rows where all obs columns are not null and ID is >100?

It is easy to get the set of columns names in Oracle

```
SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME
                            FROM   ALL_TAB_COLS, Table1 
                            WHERE  table_name = 'Table1 '
                            AND  COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'Obs%'  ;
```

But how can I combine this to something like this (in pseudo-code because the below does not work of course):

```
select * from Table1 Where ColName in ( SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME
                            FROM   ALL_TAB_COLS, Table1 
                            WHERE  table_name = 'Table1 '
                            AND  COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'obs%' ) 
And ColName.Value is Not Null and Table1.Id >100;
```

I know I can setup a query using dynamic sql, but is it possible to use some kind of transpose trick to obtain the result.  I would prefer not to use PL-SQL if a simple query was available.

EDIT:  solution with VIEW proposed is clever :)  I should add that I would like to avoid adding Views, in addition, it would be really nice if I did not have to enumerate the cols by using a similar select as my selection of columns.  This way the solution scales when new columns are added.

Comment: You'll have to list all columns in some way, there's no short-cut.

Comment: @jarlh, *You'll have to list all columns* Not necessary. You could use a xmlquery to do it in SQL without writing a single column name. See my answer.

Comment: @shev72, You can try to use exists and PIVOT in subquery but all those dynamic solutions will be slower than straight hardcoding of all column names in where clause. If all column names are NUMBER you can use something like:  where obs1+obs2+obs3+...+obsN is not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in SQL using **xmlquery**.

For example,

I want to search for the value `KING` in **all the columns** of **all the tables** in the entire `SCOTT` schema.

```
SQL> variable val varchar2(10)
SQL> exec :val := 'KING'

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR (:val, 1, 11) "Searchword",
  2    SUBSTR (table_name, 1, 14) "Table",
  3    SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 14) "Column"
  4  FROM cols,
  5    TABLE (xmlsequence (dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype ('select '
  6    || column_name
  7    || ' from '
  8    || table_name
  9    || ' where upper('
 10    || column_name
 11    || ') like upper(''%'
 12    || :val
 13    || '%'')' ).extract ('ROWSET/ROW/*') ) ) t
 14  ORDER BY "Table"
 15  /

Searchword  Table          Column
----------- -------------- --------------
KING        EMP            ENAME

SQL>
```

I have demonstrated few examples [here](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/sql-to-search-for-a-value-in-all-columns-of-all-atbles-in-an-entire-schema/).

In your case, add the filter `AND  COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'obs%'` to filter the columns that you want to search for.

Comment: This looks really close to what I need!  I simplified it to adapt it to my case:  SELECT 'test',column_name FROM cols, TABLE (xmlsequence (dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype ('select '
      || column_name || ' from Table1  where upper('
     || column_name  || ') like upper(''myTestVal'')').extract ('ROWSET/ROW/*') ) ) ;    However this is giving me the error ORA-00904: "ID": invalid identifier.  However the ID column is deifintely in table1.  Any ideas.  I am unfortunately not familiar with xmlquery which looks really powerful!

Comment: Just add this `where table_name='Table1 '` in the end. Try this `SELECT 'test',
  column_name
FROM cols,
  TABLE (xmlsequence (dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype ('select '
  || column_name
  || ' from Table1 where upper('
  || column_name
  || ') like upper(''myTestVal'')').extract ('ROWSET/ROW/*') ) ) ;
WHERE table_name='Table1';`

Comment: It works!  This is a very elegant and concise solution to a problem I have had to deal with many times,  should have asked the question on SO a long time ago.  unfortunately not easy to google search for an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

you could create a view which has all the columns concatenated together, so if this column is null then you know they are all null (bit messy but in theory would work). You may also be able to use the CALCULATED column functionality, but i'm not sure if this allows for non-numeric fields or not

dave